# Regex to look for phrase that may have whitespace before/after it?

Tags: regex

Looking for help with a regex to do a phrase match where there may be extra whitespace before and/or after the phrase:

eg the regex would match "this phrase", " this phrase", "this phrase " or " this phrase "

Totally new to regex and been looking for this answer, the best I can come up with is:
(this\sphrase)

Comment: Try using `\s*this\sphrase\s*`

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a regex that matches strings that ONLY contain "this phrase" with optional whitespace before or after "this phrase", then the following regex should work

```
^\s*this phrase\s*$
```

If you want to do some regex testing on your own, [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) is a useful regex expression resource with a quick reference guide. While the site says it is specifically Ruby oriented, I believe it works with most regex implementations. You can find a prepared example [here](http://rubular.com/r/oJiWWoAILw).

Comment: Thank you for the Rubular link.